# Почему нельзя подписать все пакеты в интернете?

Tags: сеть, tcp, tcp-ip, идентификация

Экономист Лопатников предложил метод деанонимизации в Интернете https://sl-lopatnikov.livejournal.com/2414600.html
Вкратце, нужно добавить "блок", идентифицирующий человека, к каждому пакету.
Это возможно? Мне кажется, что схема слишком уязвима и легко ломается.

Comment: Да почему ж нельзя? Если очень захотеть, то, как известно, можно в космос полететь. Только вот трудо- и фондозатратно это. Если яснее — то это выглядит примерно как "а вот если построить сферу Дайсона, то проблема дефицита энергоресурсов будет решена". Правда? Правда.

Comment: Сделать можно. не проблема. Вот только другим нормальным странам такое не нужно, а менять протокол ради одной-двух стран - никто не будет. Но никто не мешает это сделать уже сейчас - называется vpn.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev
А как насчёт взломоусточивости? Мне казалось, что достаточно посмотреть траффик в сети (сеть же открыта), скопировать "блок" от чужого пакета, присоединить "блок" к своему пакету, и пакет спокойно уйдёт.
Т.е. проблема идентификации не решена.

Comment: @KoVadim
пакеты между клиентом и VPN сервером спокойно передаются по сети. А в предложении сказано, что все узлы должны фильтровать траффик. Т.е. несколько другая схема.

Comment: Совсем все узлы фильтровать не смогут. По определению. С другой стороны, к примеру, зачем моему домашнему сайту фильтровать каких то пользоватей Лопатникова. Их отфильтрует для меня Роскомнадзор.

Comment: Такой интернет безусловно нужно предоставить всем политикам, а нормальным людям оставить нормальный. А ещё лучше переселить их всех на северный полюс, пусть там свои законы придумывают хоть каждый день друг для друга.

Comment: @Виктор мы о концепции или о технических тонкостях реализации? Если о концепции, так я уже сказал, а если о реализации — так проектирование процесс непростой и небесплатный, да и вообще не ко мне это — концлагеря проектировать...

Comment: Спасибо всем за комментарии.

Comment: @KoVadim в протоколе много пустых дырок, куда можно положить дополнительные данные - менять его в других странах не нужно

Comment: ок, ложите. Но не удивляйтесь, если другие роутеры и прочие устройства будут ложить на такие пакеты.

Comment: @KoVadim, это же "хорошо". Это же сколько бюджетов можно выделить на производство "отечественных" импортозамещённых устройств, не кладущих на такие пакеты :)

Comment: да сколько угодно. Чем быстрее, тем лучше. Желательно, что бы фильтровало посильнее. Спокойнее будет в интернете.

Answer (score 0):

Например в пакете ipv4 есть блок https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Options В него можно вставлять опции на пограничном шлюзе провайдера привязав пакет к абоненту через билинг. Использование опций не ломает протоколы интернета.

Но зачем, когда есть СОРМ и Netflow, по которым можно найти человека перебрав сохраненную историю.

Пометки пакетов можно убрать через прокси или впн. Они не решают ни одной проблемы идентификации пользователей.